# Laravel Nova Delete On Any Resource

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I have a serious problem with Laravel Nova as all of my resources delete function is not functioning as it does.

whenever i press the delete icon on a row this error is being returned by the console

[image]

Does any one faced the same problem so we can discuss the possible work-around .

Comment: is there any error in the backend logs?

Comment: the error in the console is logged before the request goes to the server just like that : - click on the icon ( delete ) , log console error , stop execution of the request